# How to use JSON to get value?

Tags: java, android, json

```
            Log.d("Hot Text:", response.toString());
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("rows");
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray a = jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements");
                JSONObject js = a.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject b = js.getJSONObject("distance");
                value = b.getString("value");
                Log.d("TAG", "title:" + value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

how to get "value" to storage for other space? thank u

Comment: can you please explain what you exactly want to ask?

Comment: When I use TRY CATCH, there is a value, but after the end it is NULL.

Comment: plz share your json, I'll check this

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?

Comment: units=imperial&origins=23.575593,119.580992&destinations=23.573528, 119.572441
&key=AIzaSyCZU4V9ST8HqM46KrQilnJv6iLrukUaIqk

Comment: JSON & LOCATION  Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
String text;
int value;
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
     JSONArray rowArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("rows");
     if(rowArray.length() > 0){
       JSONObject row = rowArray.optJSONObject(0);
       JSONArray elementArray = row.optJSONArray("elements");
       if(elementArray.length() > 0){
         JSONObject element = elementArray.optJSONObject(0);
         JSONObject distance = element.optJSONObject("distance");
         text = distance.optString("text");
         value = distance.optInt("value");
       }
     }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
Log.e("text", text);
Log.e("value", "value : " + value);
```